# Order by Recursion tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have tried determining the running time given by a recurrence relation, but my result is not correct.

**Recurrence**

```
T(n) = c + T(n-1) if n >= 1
     = d          if n = 0
```

**My attempt**

I constructed this recursion tree:

```
                   n
                   |
                  n-1
                   |
                  n-2
                   |
                  n-3
                   |
                  n-4
                   |
                  n-5
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |
                Till we get 1
```

Now at level `i`, the size of the sub problem should be, `n-i`

But at last we want a problem of size 1. Thus, at the last level,  `n-i=1` which gives, `i=n-1`.

So the depth of the tree becomes `n-1` and the height becomes `n-1+1= n`.

Now the time required to solve this recursion = height of the tree*time required at each level which is :

```
n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-5)+ ...
==> (n+n+n+n+n+ ... )-(1+2+3+4+5+ ... )
==> n - (n(n+1)/2)
```

Now the time taken = n* ((n-n2)/2) which should give the order to be n<sup>2</sup>, but that is not the correct answer.

Comment: yeah u r right.. but the way i solve it, does it seems wrong?

Comment: @user975234 If it didn't, why do you think you don't get the right answer?

Comment: @phant0m: Thats what i am asking, tell me where i am wrong!

Comment: You have not transcribed your question correctly. Is it supposed to be `n >= 1` or `n <= 1` ?

Comment: eh!? it is written there: 

T(n) = c + T(n-1); if n>1
     = d; if n<1

Comment: it will be for n>=1 T(n) = c + T(n-1) 

     = d; if n<1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now at level i, the size of the sub problem should be, n-i

Yes, that is correct. But you're assuming, that the runtime equals the sum of all the subproblem sizes. Just think about it, already summing the first two levels gives `n + (n - 1) = 2n - 1`, why would the problem size increase? <sub>Disclaimer: A bit handwavy and not an entirely accurate statement.</sub>

### What the formula actually says

```
T(n) = c + T(n-1)
```

The formula says, solving it for some `n` takes the same time it takes to solve it for a problem size that is one less, *plus* an additional constant `c`: `c + T(n - 1)`

Another way to put the above statement is this: Given the problem takes some time `t` for a certain problem size, it will take `t + c` for a problem size, that is bigger by one.

We know, that at a problem size of `n = 0`, this takes time `d`. According to the second statement, for a size of one more, `n = 1`, it will take `d + c`. Applying our rule again, it thus takes `d + c + c` for `n = 2`. We conclude, that it must take `d + n*c` time for any `n`.

<sub>*This* is not a proof. To actually prove this, you must use induction as shown by amit.</sub>

### A correct recursion tree

Your recursion tree only lists the problem size. That's pretty much useless, I'm afraid. Instead, you need to list the runtime for said problem size.

Every node in the tree *corresponds* to a certain problem size. What you write into that node is the *additional* time it takes for the problem size. I.e. you sum over all the descendants of a node *plus* the node itself to get the runtime for a certain problem size.

A graphical representation of such a tree would look like this

```
Tree        Corresponding problem size
c                                    n
|
c                                    n - 1
|
c                                    n - 2
|
c                                    n - 3
.
.
.
|
c                                    2
|
c                                    1
|
d                                    0
```

**Formalizing:** As already mentioned, the label of a node is the *additional* runtime it takes to solve for that problem size, plus all its descendants. The uppermost node represents a problem size of `n`, bearing the label `c` because that's in addition to `T(n-1)`, to which it is connected using a `|`.

In a formula, you would only write this relation: `T(n) = c + T(n-1)`. Given that tree, you can see how this applies to every `n>=1`. You could write this down like this:

```
T(n)     = c + T(n - 1) # This means, `c` plus the previous level
T(n - 1) = c + T(n - 2) # i.e. add the runtime of this one to the one above^
T(n - 2) = c + T(n - 3)
...
T(n - (n - 2)) = c + T(1)
T(n - (n - 1)) = c + T(0)
T(0) = d
```

You can now expand the terms from bottom to top:

```
T(n - (n - 1)) = c + T(0)
T(0) = d

T(n - (n - 2)) = c + T(1)
T(n - (n - 1)) = c + d
T(0) = d

T(n - (n - 3)) = c + T(2)
T(n - (n - 2)) = c + (c + d)
T(n - (n - 1)) = c + d
T(0) = d

T(n - (n - 4)) = c + T(3)
T(n - (n - 3)) = c + (2*c + d)
T(n - (n - 2)) = c + (c + d)

...

T(n) = c + T(n - 1)
T(n - 1) = c + ((n-2)c + d)

T(n) = c + (n-1)c + d = n*c + d
T(n - 1) = (n-1)c + d
```

### Summing `1 to n`

```
n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+(n-4)+(n-5)+ ...
==> (n+n+n+n+n+ ... )-(1+2+3+4+5+ ... )
==> n - (n(n+1)/2)
```

From the first line to the second line, you have reduced your problem from summing `1 to n` to, well, summing `1 to n-1`. That's not very helpful, because you're stuck with the same problem.

I'm not sure what you did on the third line, but your transition from the first to the second is basically correct.

This would have been the correct formula:

[image: gauss' trick to sum 1 to n]

Comment: @user975234 You're welcome. Just note that the first argument is somewhat incorrect without the part in "What the formula actually says". Also, I have added a section about your summation at the end.

Comment: yeah .. i was thinking about it .. coz, it does not actually increase the problem size.. if u see the first example in this page: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/lectures/lec19-master/master.htm .. it solves in pretty much the same way !! the only difference is that the extra amount of work is not constant! Thats why i am still in doubt if my approach is wrong! :|

Comment: If possible please see and tell! i am a bit confused rite nw

Comment: The issue is that you got confused because they use only the variable `n`. If you wanted to construct a recursion tree in the same fashion, it would only read `c` at every node. You will notice, that all their nodes are `something^2`, that's because the non-recursive part of the formula is `n^2`, whereas your formula has `c`. I.e. from top(left) to bottom(right), it would read like this: `c-c-c-....-c-c-d`

Comment: @user975234 I have added a visualization of the tree and a more expansive explanation.

Comment: i agree the tree should c-c-c-c-c-c- .. but if it is so, then i will sum these c+c+c+c+c ... = cn .. now the total time taken should be cn * n because the height of the tree should be n . .which again gives the order n2! :| ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17670/discussion-between-user975234-and-phant0m)

Answer (score 2):

```
T(n) = c + T(n-1) 
     = c + (c + T(n-2)) 
     = ... 
     = c*i + T(n-i) 
     = ...
     = c*n + T(0)
     = c*n + d
```

If we assume c,d are constants - it gets you `O(n)`

To prove it mathematically - one can use [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

For each `k < n` assume `T(n) = c*n + d`

Base is `T(0) = 0*n + d = d`, which is correct for n < 1

```
T(n) = c + T(n-1)               (*)
     = c + (n-1)*c + d 
     = c*n + d
```

(*) is the induction hypothesis, and is valid since n-1 < n

Comment: Yours is short and right :P is my solution wrong in any way ?

Comment: @user975234: You don't need to *sum* n + (n-1) + ..., the recursion is not `T(n) = c*n + T(n-1)` - (if it was, the analysis was correct). It is `T(n) = c + T(n-1)` - the addition is not a function of `n`.

Comment: may be i am wrong in here but as far as i know.. this question means.. that i am dividing the problem size n to n-1 and so on doing a constant amount of work at each level i.e c.. so to calculate the time i need to sum n + (n-1) + ... , Is there a restriction on using recursion tree if the work done is not a function of n ? I am sorry, a novice! :|

Comment: @user975234 No, there is not, but your recursion tree is just wrong.

Comment: Your closed form indicates, that question should read `if n>=1`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity would be O(n).

As you described the functions converts the problem for input n into problem for (n-1) by using a constant operation 'c'.

So moving down the recursion tree we will have in total n levels, and at each step we require some constant operation 'c'.

So there will be total c*n operations resulting into the complexity O(n).